# Finding the unknown correlations to data from an image

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, neural-networks, statistical-significance

I have a complex image of a biological device, and I have the results of the device being used as a data frame collected from other sources.

I want a predictive model to say this image will create these results, but first, I want to see if any variables are correlated. Not all the output data is correlated, but I don't know which ones.

I had one idea to train a transfer learned CNN model and then create new data and measure the error across the variables between the datasets to know which variables are the most correlated. The main worry for this method is that if I overfit, I won't tell correlated values from noncorrelated values.

Is there another method I'm unaware of for discovering which variables are the most useful?